# Finite model or no models?

Tags: first-order-logic

An FO sentence has the finite model property
if either it has no model or it has at least one finite model.
Show that it is undecidable if an FO sentence has the finite model property.

Any hints?

Comment: Hint: assume for contradiction that this is decidable, and show that the set of sentences that have a (finite or infinite) model is recursively enumerable, and consequently that first-order logic is decidable. Which it is not.

Comment: So, I know by Godel's completeness theorem that the set of valid sentences is recursively enumerable. We can enumerate valid sentences and decide whether they have the finite model property, but that doesn't enumerate all sentences with a finite or infinite model because some sentence may be satisfiable by only finite models (in which case it would not be emmited by the enumerator for the set of valid sentences).

Comment: Yes. Now, think how to enumerate sentences satisfiable in a finite model.

Comment: I think I got it, thank you!!